# How to know when user doesn't click anymore on a button WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm doing some password eye text box.

I want, that when the user would press on the eye button, the password would be visible and when he leaves the mouse button it would be unvisible again.

My question: How to know when the user stopped clicking the mouse button?

Image of how it looks like:

[image]

My code is roughly as follows:

```
private void eye_click(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e)
{         
    //here I making the password visible
}
```

**I'm looking for something like:**

```
private void user_doesnt_click_anymore_click(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e)
{         
    //return the password to be unvisible
}
```

Comment: have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Use `MouseUp` and `MouseDown` instead of `Click`

Comment: Be aware that a Button's Click handler isn't called before the mouse button is *released*. You probably don't need a Button at all. Attach MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonUp handlers directly to an Image element.

Comment: @Clemens please add a code snippet as answer if u can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess you could go for something in the area of MouseDown/MouseUp

```
<Button x:Name="Btn" MouseDown="MouseDown" MouseUp="MouseUp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can react to different events, depending on your

#### Form-Example

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
this.button1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.button1_MouseClick);
this.button1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.button1_MouseDown);
this.button1.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.button1_MouseUp);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("button1_Click");
}

private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("button1_MouseClick");
}

private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("button1_MouseDown");
}

private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("button1_MouseUp");
}
```

#### MouseDown

Fires if you mouse is over the button an a mousebutton is pushed down.

- First chance to see something
- Here you want to show the pw.

#### MouseUp

Fires if you release the mousebutton which you "downed" on the button.

- Fired when stopped clicking. You're not neccessarily on the button anymore!
- Here you want to hide the pw.

#### MouseClick

Fires if a MouseDown AND MouseUp is performed and you're still hovering the button.

- This prevents hitting buttons with the keyboard. Perhaps helpful in some situations?!

#### Click

Fires if the button is clicked (Pushed down and released). This could also be done my selecting the button by tabbing to it and pushing space.

- This is what you normally want to use, when a button is clicked, like "submit form"-actions.